# Using Thread to map a two variable function

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following function:

```
magicFunction[ lst_, val_ ] := Fold[ ((#2 < val) && #1) &, True, lst ]
```

It works

```
In[]=:magicFunction[{6,7},9] 
Out[]= True
```

I want to Map the function. To do it I use Thread.

If I use Thread for a noname function with the list I want to map, the following is produced:

```
In[]:= Thread[f[{{6,7},{2,3},{1,2}},{9, 10,5}]]
Out[]= {f[{6,7},9],f[{2,3},10],f[{1,2},5]}
```

That is exactly what I want to do.

However, when I use `magicFunction` that is not what I get. If I use `magicFunction` I should get the following:

```
Out[]:= {magicFunction[{6,7},9],magicFunction[{2,3},10],magicFunction[{1,2},5]}
```

which then evaluates to:

```
Out[]:= {True, True, True}
```

However what I get is the following:

```
In[]:= Thread[magicFunction[{{6,7},{2,3},{1,2}},{9, 10,5}]]

Out[]:= {1,2}<{9,10,5}&&{2,3}<{9,10,5}&&{6,7}<{9,10,5}
```

Does anybody know what I m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Your issue is that `magicFunction` evaluated before [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) could do anything. One idea to avoid this is to use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated):

```
Thread[Unevaluated @ magicFunction[{{6,7},{2,3},{1,2}},{9,10,5}]]
```

> {True, True, True}

Another idea is to add an argument restriction to your `magicFunction`. Since [`Less`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Less) only makes sense for numeric quantities, you can use:

```
Clear[magicFunction]
magicFunction[lst_, val_?NumericQ] := Fold[((#2<val)&&#1)&,True,lst]
```

Then:

```
Thread[magicFunction[{{6,7},{2,3},{1,2}},{9,10,5}]]
```

> {True, True, True}

Answer (score 7):

You can  use `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[magicFunction, {{{6, 7}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}}, {9, 10, 5}}]
```

> {True, True, True}